# Anniversary date gets change on IOS 5 when timezone changed

Tags: ios5, ios6

When I add any contact to AddressBook, birthday and anniversary date get change when timezone is changed. But anniversary date getting change !!! not a good sign :).

I checked some third party apps they also have same problem.

But when I checked with FB its working fine.

installed FB app on device with version ios6.
In settings enabled contacts for FB to sync.

When I change timezone the date's in contacts that are synced form FB do not change but what I add from my app will get change.

What format should be used to write date, so that it should not change based on timezone. As I see with Facebook app now.

Any contact synced from FB to local AB can not be edited. Is this is the reason that dates are not getting changed for contacts that are added from FB.

Thanks in Advance.
Sha